# Locating Categories on a wikepedia page

Tags: vb.net, search

So in short I have a task where I need to read off the title of a random wikepedia page as well as all of the categories within it

I have sucesfully (but very inefficently) managed to find the title by calling in the html off the page and searching for title but I cannot figure out how to find the categories... any ideas?

```
Sub Main()
        'this holds the webadress
         Dim webadress As String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Day_Baptists"
        'this causes the loop to keep going until title of page has been located
        Dim titlefound As Boolean = False
        'reads the entire html off of the wikepedia page
        Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(webadress)
        'holds the position at which the title is within the html
        Dim position As Integer
        'used to compile the title out of the html
        Dim title As String
        'loops until title found
        While titlefound <> True
            'used to flick through each character of html(aware its inefficent but easiest way I could think of)
            For i = 0 To sourceString.Length()
            'checks if its reading title
                If sourceString(i) = "t" And sourceString(i + 1) = "i" And sourceString(i + 2) = "t" And sourceString(i + 3) = "l" And sourceString(i + 4) = "e" Then
                    Console.WriteLine("locating title...")
                    Console.WriteLine("found")
                    position = i + 6
                    titlefound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next


        End While
    'searches for the hyphen after the title to determin when the title stops
        For i = position To 100000
            If sourceString(i) = "-" Then
                Exit For
            End If
            title = title & sourceString(i)

        Next
'displays the title
        Console.Write("the title is: ")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        console.writeline(title)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Load the HTML page using a WebBrowser class object (not the Control), or [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/): then, you'll have all the tools needed to parse that page properly. Note that the [HtmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument), returned by the WebBrowser, already contains many pre-built collections: the `Links` collection, among the others. The Title is also already *parsed*, of course. I.e., use the right tools for the job.

Comment: @jimi so i'm an A level student and don't really get anything you said you think you could dumb it down for me a bit? Also from what I picked up , agility cant be used inside a online sandbox which I have to complete this task in (as a result can only use built in vb libaries)

Comment: If you have specific requirements, specific constraints and specific instructions on how to complete this task (homework?) and the tools that are allowed, you need to add these details to your question, otherwise any possible answer is likely to *miss the target*.